# Gradle build error: cannot find symbol for mInstabug.setUserName(username)

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native, instabug

Having a background as web developer, I have recently started with app development in react-native, using android-studio and struck at this gradle build error, when I try to run command:

```
react-native run-android
```

it outputs this:

> cannot find symbol
>               *mInstabug.setUserName(username);*
>
> - method setUserName(String)
> - location: variable mInstabug of type Instabug
> - **Note:** D:\my_project\node_modules\instab reactnative\android\src\main\java\com\instabug\react
>     library\RNInstabugReactnativeModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
> - **Note:** Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Execution failed for task ':instabug-reactnative:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

I am Currently Using:

- "instabug-reactnative": "git+https://github.com/Instabug/instabug-reactnative.git#master"
- "react-native": "0.42.3"

*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: Format commands and code snippets with backticks (`) or add 4 spaces of indentation before each line of code.

Comment: ok,,. will follow it from now on...

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem.  I think I found the issue and can provide a temporary solution until the developer can update his module.  If you refer to the link below we will likely get more feedback from the developer.

https://github.com/Instabug/instabug-reactnative/issues/36

The temporary solution:

In the RNInstabugReactnativeModule file located here on your machine:

```
D:\my_project\node_modules\instab reactnative\android\src\main\java\com\instabug\react library\RNInstabugReactnativeModule.java
```

starting at line 183:

```
@ReactMethod
public void setUserName(String username) {
    try {
        mInstabug.setUserName(username);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

change the try statement's mInstabug.setUserName to mInstabug.setUsername:

```
@ReactMethod
public void setUserName(String username) {
    try {
        mInstabug.setUsername(username);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It looks like the developer changed the casing to be more consistent with iOS but I suppose it has not been updated on the mInstabug class yet.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in version 1.0.8.
https://github.com/Instabug/instabug-reactnative/releases/tag/v1.0.8